# Data mismatch in View2 [SELECT * from View1] with View1, how to fix?

Tags: postgresql, view, postgresql-9.6

The problem I encounter can be oversimplied as

```
CREATE View#2 AS SELECT * FROM View#1;
SELECT * FROM View#2;
SELECT * FROM View#1;
```

Then View#1 and View#2 return different results. This challenges logic but it's not a logic issue. Both View#1 and View#2 are created years ago in a years-old production database.

A simple test in the same schema,

```
CREATE View#3 AS SELECT * FROM View#1;
SELECT * FROM View#3;
SELECT * FROM View#1;
```

can not repilcate the problem.

It's a production database. I haven't fix by replacing the view. Just in the hope that I can get help to look further into the cause and verify the integerity of the database at some level. (maybe inspecting stuff in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` etc. I am totaly new to such issue and haven't used Postgres for years due to project change. Some checklist points will be appreciated)

--- prev post with detail -----------------------------

For the details, I think the following session speak for all.

```
-- trying to audit utlog weighed stat 
with t as (
select '2020-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp t0, '2020--07-02 0:0:0'::timestamp t1
)
--select * from t;
select * 
-- from utlog.cache_stats_per_shift_per_reason_weighed_stats 
-- from utlog.stats_per_shift_filtered_per_reason
from utlog.stats_per_shift_filtered    (#View2)
-- from utlog.stats_per_shift_filtered_b0206 (#View1)
-- from utlog.stats_per_shift
cross join t
where wline = 'F02'  and wts >= t.t0 and wts < t.t1 and wsft ='D'
-- limit 100 (the above condition returns only 5 results)
;
```

The Result for #View2

```
wts                 | wsft | wspan  | wstate | wline | rcodes
--------------------+------+--------+--------+-------+-------
2020-07-01 08:00:00 | D    |      0 | S00    | F02   | {PDCB}
2020-07-01 09:50:01 | D    | 12.533 | S00    | F02   | {PDCB}
2020-07-01 11:35:46 | D    | 12.217 | S00    | F02   | {CDSO}
2020-07-01 13:22:58 | D    |   5.15 | S00    | F02   | {PDCB}
2020-07-01 14:57:38 | D    |    6.8 | S00    | F02   | {PDCB}

INDEX | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE  
------+-------------+------------
1     | wts         | timestamptz
3     | wsft        | varchar    
4     | wspan       | float8     
5     | wstate      | varchar    
6     | wline       | varchar    
7     | rcodes      | text[]
```

Same query, the Result for #View1

```
wts                 | wsft | wspan | wstate | wline | rcodes
--------------------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------
2020-07-01 08:00:00 | D    |     5 | S00    | F02   | {PDCB}
2020-07-01 09:50:01 | D    |    13 | S00    | F02   | {PDCB}
2020-07-01 11:35:46 | D    |    12 | S00    | F02   | {CDSO}
2020-07-01 13:22:58 | D    |     5 | S00    | F02   | {PDCB}
2020-07-01 14:57:38 | D    |     7 | S00    | F02   | {PDCB}

INDEX | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE  
------+-------------+------------
1     | wts         | timestamptz
3     | wsft        | varchar    
4     | wspan       | float8     
5     | wstate      | varchar    
6     | wline       | varchar    
7     | rcodes      | varchar[]
```

Reuslts in `wspan` column is inaccurate while both type are float8. Most weird thing is the 5 to 0 change. for Row 1.

Definition of View2 (SQLWorkbench/J generated schema):

(The `_b0206` is just a version of `stats_per_shift_filtered` from past revisions. The original CREATE statement must be `AS SELECT * FROM ...._b0206` )

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW utlog.stats_per_shift_filtered (#View2)
(
wts,
wdate,
wsft,
wspan,
wstate,
wline,
rcodes
)
AS 
SELECT stats_per_shift_filtered_u0206.wts,
    stats_per_shift_filtered_u0206.wsft::character varying AS wsft,
    stats_per_shift_filtered_u0206.wspan,
    stats_per_shift_filtered_u0206.wstate,
    stats_per_shift_filtered_u0206.wline,
    stats_per_shift_filtered_u0206.rcodes
FROM utlog.stats_per_shift_filtered_u0206;  (as #View1 in this post)
```

Comment: you have a `limit` without an `order by` - that is not guaranteed to return the same set of rows each time. If you need a consistent result, you have to add an `order by`

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name, the rows in the result for view1 and view2 may differ because they are different rows. Remove limit or add an order by that uniquely order the rows to get comparable results.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I have revised the post, hopefully it made the problem more clear ?